# How to convert an URDF to SDF with Gazebo Ignition?

Tags: gazebo-ignition, sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

In Gazebo classic I could convert URDF to SDF using `gz sdf -p /my_urdf.urdf > /my_sdf.sdf`.
But it seems Gazebo Ignition doesn't install this tool.

How do you convert URDF to SDF with Gazebo Ignition ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/28393/how-to-convert-an-urdf-to-sdf-with-gazebo-ignition-?/) by [Clement](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/84310/clement/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-08-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

https://github.com/osrf/subt/wiki/Model-Migration-Guide

```
ign sdf -p mpo_700.urdf > mpo_700.sdf
```

---

Originally posted by [pmuthu2s](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8437/pmuthu2s/) with karma: 28 on 2022-08-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1